# How can I create a Sagemaker endpoint for this notebook?

Tags: python, machine-learning, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a VectorDB (FAISS) and input PDF's into it. Then i'm using the Langchain wrappper for AWS Bedrock to call it. I know Kowledge Bases exist now, but at least in the SageMaker notebook, i have a bit more control. The model works perfectly in SageMaker Notebook, when i ask a question, it returns the answer.

What I would like to do is create a little web page (and via HTTP/REST API), just submit the question in a text field and receive the answer in a text field. I'm guessing this is pretty difficult to do without a Lambda function somewhere in the chain, or maybe not?

When I look in my Sagemaker Console, under **Inference** tab, there is **no** Model or **no** Endpoint, or **no** Endpoint Configurations (as i'm not selecting a model from Sagemaker, i just use langchain LLM and Bedrock in the Python notebook as below).

```
import boto3
import json 

bedrock = boto3.client(service_name="bedrock")
bedrock_runtime = boto3.client(service_name="bedrock-runtime")



from langchain.llms.bedrock import Bedrock
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

embeddings = BedrockEmbeddings(model_id="amazon.titan-embed-text-v1",
                               client=bedrock_runtime)
```

Eventually i emdbed the docs into the FAISS Vector database, and it's this database I query

```
db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)


model_titan = { 
    "maxTokenCount": 512,
    "stopSequences": [],
    "temperature":0.0,  
    "topP":0.5
}

# Amazon Titan Model
llm = Bedrock(
    model_id="amazon.titan-text-express-v1", 
    client=bedrock_runtime, 
    model_kwargs=model_titan,
)
```

Then define a prompt.....

```
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"]
)
```

And query the database:

```
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=db.as_retriever(
        search_type="similarity",
    ),
    return_source_documents=True,
    chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": PROMPT},
)



query = "What does the future tech look like?"

result = qa({"query": query})

print(f'Query: {result["query"]}\n')
print(f'Result: {result["result"]}\n')
print(f'Context Documents: ')
for srcdoc in result["source_documents"]:
      print(f'{srcdoc}\n')
```

This returns exactly what i need within Sagemaker, I just need to query the database externally.

I don't want to have a lambda function rebuild the chain each time. I'm thinking for efficiency, all I need is to pass a query in the lambda function and return the result.

[image: Code to run?]

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippets you provided it looks like you are savings the embeddings locally in the notebook using a local FAAIS db. You can consider decoupling the vector db by saving the embedding say in OpenSearch, Aurora or maybe even use Kendra (No requirement to create the embeddings in the first place).

OpenSearch blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-a-powerful-question-answering-bot-with-amazon-sagemaker-amazon-opensearch-service-streamlit-and-langchain/

Kendra blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/simplify-access-to-internal-information-using-retrieval-augmented-generation-and-langchain-agents/

While these blogs showcase SageMaker as the service which hosts the model, you can use Bedrock as the service for LLM inference. Bedrock is a separate service to SageMaker and is serverless. From the code shared there is no creation or usage of SageMaker components.

Aurora blog (Bedrock): https://community.aws/concepts/vector-embeddings-and-rag-demystified-2

Once you have decoupled the vector DB, you can host the langchain application (which would search the vector DB and pass the results to the model) on any web server you like.

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you. I would like to make use of Bedrock as you only pay when queries are made, its not in permanent use (cost efficient). would this be the example to use for this:    https://github.com/generative-ai-on-aws/generative-ai-on-aws/blob/1cc81c1a518282fc7c6b2a92d97bfc5faef17d2b/12_bedrock/16_opensearch_serverless_titan_embeddings_claude.ipynb                                 It looks like its run in Sagemaker too, however it still perhaps appears to not let me call it from outside Sagemaker. Is there a way to set this up so i could? So perhaps there's that final piece missing?

Comment: Yeah that example can be used. The mention of SageMaker is just where you would run the notebook on SageMaker studio. You could run the notebook locally if you have set up your AWS creds correctly.

Comment: Thanks Marc, so at the end of that example i linked, it looks like the embedding is done (i'm assuming in the code its done once to get the docs in there), and once its done, i'd then uncomment the  #docsearch bit of the code and run the rest (see pic in original post).   I've added a picture to the original post, so my assumption is that this is the code i'd need to run in a .py file putside Sagemaker to just do the query/answer bit?